# How to: derived member in derived class with derived class specific methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, template-specialization

I am using C++ under Ubuntu 11.10 and the latest version of NetBeans. Let's say I have the 
following code:

```
class Node {}
class DerivedNode : public Node {}

class Graph {
    vector<Node*> nodes;
}

class DerivedGraph : public Graph { }
```

At the moment I'm storing DerivedNodes in the DerivedGraph class like this for example:

```
nodes.push_back(new DerivedNode());
```

When I need to use specific methods that only apply to DerivedNodes and DerivedGraphs 
I am forced to use a dynamic_cast on my Node pointers first.

I would like to be able to have specific methods in DerivedGraph which apply only to DerivedNodes
and avoid the need of casting pointers. I do not mind having to redesign my classes if the end
result is better than what I have.

I am sure there must be a clean and simple method to achieve the same thing I'm trying to do.
Maybe something with specialized templates? Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly 
appreciated. I'll also provide any additional information required in the case I haven't been too
clear.

EDIT: I don't have two copies. I wanted to put emphasis on how it looks. I apologize for the presentation. What I want to obtain is:

```
class DerivedGraph: public Graph {
    vector<DerivedNode*> nodes;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have **two** copies of `nodes`??

Comment: @Morat: Check again.  `DerivedGraph` has a `nodes` member, and it _also_ inherits `Graph`'s `nodes` member.  So `DerivedGraph` has two `nodes` members.

Comment: I understood what you said. I'll re-edit my original question as it seems to generate confusion. My actual code does not have the nodes container twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* that your interface in `Node` is appropriate? Sometimes when you find yourself needing to downcast (especially in a case like this where base pointers are stored in a container) that may be a signal that your abstract interface doesn't cover all your needs properly. Often something like the Template Method pattern solves all your needs without needing a downcast at all.

However, assuming that your inheritance model really need work in such a way, what you probably want to do is have virtual methods that get overridden in `DerivedGraph` for adding and getting nodes. You *will* have to verify the node type and downcast it in this case.

One final approach is to have two separate containers, one in the parent that contains all nodes that aren't `DerivedNode` and then another container in `DerivedGraph` that contains all the `DerivedNode`. Then you use overridden functions again to determine which container to access depending on your API needs.

Comment: I think that being new here I'm having issues in describing my problems. Would the following detail change your advice in any way: I know for sure that the DerivedGraph must and will only contain DerivedNodes. I need the DerivedGraph to have all the functionality of the normal Graph plus a few extra ones, but nevertheless it will contain only DerivedNodes. That's the reason why I thought this might be solvable with specialized templates. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Start by not duplicating your data member in the derived class.

Then add virtual member functions that you use to add data to your container. That way you can create instances of derived types in the derived class and add them to the container.

Finally, when you override the virtual function that returns a reference to data in the derived class, use [covariant return types](http://www.lwithers.me.uk/articles/covariant.html).

Comment: Yes, but when I have methods in the DerivedGraph which need access to members of a DerivedNode I still need to cast a Node pointer to a DerivedNode pointer. Any way to avoid the cast?

Comment: You can't avoid casting altogether, but if the invariant of your class guarantees that the cast will always succeed you can avoid the run-time cost of a `dynamic_cast` by using `static_cast`.